# Qu’est-ce qu’on dit pour faire le plein en France ?

Tags: vocabulaire, usage, transports

Quand on va à une station-service qu’est-ce qu’on dirait pour faire le plein ?

> $5 on 4.
>
> I need $10 on pump 3.

Des trucs dans le genre.

Comment: In my experience you don't say anything. The vast majority of gas station are automated self-services where no interaction with a gas station attendant will take place

Comment: @Eauquidort : In France at least, in other coutries I don't know. I remember, not that long ago, I was in a gas station and near me was a Belgian, stuck there, not knowing he had to put his credit card in the machine before using it.

Comment: @Steph : In Belgium most gas stations are automated also :-)

Comment: I am Belgian, from my own experience, Belgians travelling in France may rather be confused by the physical layout of the machines and the terminology used on terminals in France ("carte bleue" - seriously, guys ? Most cards are not even blue !).

Answer (score 7):

De mon expérience, les pompes où quelqu'un vous fait le plein ont quasiment disparu en France. Pour les pompes avec caisse, on prend soi-même le pistolet, on met la quantité voulue et on va payer au comptoir, pour les pompes 24/24, on met sa carte bancaire et on se sert.

Ceci étant dit, dans ce cas de figure, je mentionnerais le type de carburant plutôt que le numéro de pompe. Voici quelques exemples avec des variations (demande d'une somme ou d'une quantité, variations de politesse...

> 30 litres de sans-plomb 95, s'il vous plaît
>
> Je voudrais 20 euros de GPL
>
> Pouvez-vous me faire le plein de gasoil ?

etc etc. Et si on doit vraiment rajouter le numéro de pompe, par exemple :

> Pouvez-vous me faire le plein de gasoil, pompe 3 ?

Comment: Sur le point mentionné par suiiurisesse: en Belgique on dit respectivement diesel et LPG. Il serait intéressant de connaître l'usage dans le reste de la francophonie.

Comment: Au GDT : [essence](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1198723), [GPL](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2069591), [gasoil](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1199709). Il serait bien d'avoir de multiples réponses à cet effet. @Greg

Comment: Depuis quelques mois, les noms de carburant sont censés avoir été uniformisés dans l'UE et remplacés par des sigles un peu bizarres (https://www.economie.gouv.fr/particuliers/noms-carburants). Mais dans l'usage courant, les noms usuels sont toujours utilisés - à voir si dans le futur les nouvelles dénominations passeront également dans le langage courant.

Comment: J'ai eu une fois à payer au comptoir avant de me servir en France, et j'ai dit pour le coup *20€ de 95 E10 en pompe 3, merci.* Je ne crois pas qu'il existe encore des pompes où quelqu'un nous fait le plein cependant. Pour les types de carburants, en France, on a *SP 98*, *SP 95*, *SP 95 E10* et *diesel*.